# Какая разметка работает быстрее: из XML-файла или же созданная программно в java-файле?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml

Я думаю, что всё-таки из XML-файла, так как объекты созданы уже заранее, но допускаю, что причина может быть в другом.

Если это так, то могли бы Вы мне помочь разобраться с этим?

В качестве эталона для сравнения я беру в виду тот момент, когда нужно сделать 2 экрана перечисленными способами, но чтобы они отображали одно и то же.

Не важно, в каких случаях использовать тот или иной способ, мне нужно знать просто о сравнении скоростей.

Comment: В теории XML дольше - виджеты создаются точно так же программно + чтение, разбор и установка параметров из XML. На практике не всё так неоднозначно - вам всё равно придётся что-то брать из ресурсов и что-то рассчитывать при создании вью + не факт, что вы сможете всё это создать более оптимальным способом, чем разработчики Андроида. В общем, предлагаю не заморачиваться, а делать как проще и удобнее вам. Озадачиться этим вопросом стоит только если у вас уже получился непозволительно долго загружающийся интерфейс, и то сильно сомневаюсь, что перенос создания в код ощутимо поможет в таком случае.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, при инстанциации слоя из xml, `LayoutInflater` не парсит xml, т.к. в итоговом билде их нет. Насколько я помню, при сборке .apk эти ресурсы в бинарный формат перегоняются (а он читается/парсится быстрее обычной xml'ки). Да, потом они читаются, но всё это дело в нативном коде происходит, что в плане производительности вообще копейки.

Во-вторых, когда создаётся вьюха из xml, то `LayoutInflater` использует конструктор с двумя параметрами, один из которых `AttributeSet`. Там же сразу вызываются методы типо `.setText(...)`, `.setBackground(...)`. Когда вы создаёте вьюху из кода, то сами ручками вызываете эти методы, помимо этого они вызываются ещё и в конструкторе. Т.е, при программном создании некоторые методы вызываются дважды.

**TL;DR:** разница в скорости слишком незначительна.

Когда заходит речь про создание элементов кодом или посредством xml, то обычно всегда говорят про удобство разработки. Работать с xml намного удобнее и быстрее. Особенно, когда в команде много человек.

Comment: _"Работать с xml намного удобнее и быстрее."_ - повеселил)))

Comment: @Qwertiy если вы создаёте вьюхи под Android всегда из кода, то могу лишь посочувствовать вашим тиммейтам )=

Comment: @Qwertiy, таки действительно удобнее и быстрее) В отличие от iOS разметка на андроиде легка проста и очевидна. Что-то типа сильно упрощённого html, только без излишнего обилия тэгов и css свойств.

Comment: @Suvitruf, я не вообще-то веб-разработчик. Но xml я не люблю. И джаву не люблю. И не в последнюю очередь именно за xml.